# What's the meaning of this sql statement (order by count(*))?

Tags: sql

What could be the meaning of this sql statement ?

```
select * from tab1 order by (select count(*) from tab2) desc
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @AbeMiessler: Does it matter?  This is standard SQL and I don't know of a db server that would automatically join the two referenced tables.

Comment: @ChrisLively, this performing a `JOIN` is not even on my radar.  I can't say that I know everything about every DBMS out there, but it seems likely that this could do two different things in two different DBMSs.  If this is true it would matter.

Comment: The `ORDER BY (scalar subquery) ` makes no sense, not even if it were correlated. `Order by 1,2,3` would be valid, but the `1,2,3` need to be evaluated at "compile time" It _could_ be some extention, but in that case it would still be bad style, since the `SELECT *` relies on implicit order of the fields in the result tuple.

Answer (score 4):

The below line just returns the number of rows in tab2, which is some constant number

```
select count(*) from tab2
```

Consider the columns numbered 1 through n where n is the last column.

```
select * from tab1 order by 1
```

would order by the first column

```
select * from tab1 order by 2
```

would order by the second column and etc.
If n is larger than the number of columns then you'll run into a problem
**EDIT**
You are using a subquery however and having

```
select * from tbl1 order by (select 1000)
```

does not cause a problem if you have <1000 columns, it seems to do nothing; the query may be missing some information

Comment: Apparently, subqueries are treated differently than constant expressions. "select * from sysobjects order by (select 1)" is not the same as "select * from sysobjects order by 1". That's based on MS SQL

Comment: you're right, having n too large in a subquery was not causing me errors when I just tested this, will edit.

Comment: I think only `ORDER BY N` or `ORDER BY (N)` means order by Nth column. `ORDER BY 100` throws error, and so does `ORDER BY (100)`. But `ORDER BY (SELECT N)` means order by value, harmless, but also meaningless in case of constant N.

Answer (score 3):

The result is to order by the column whose index is the count returned by the inner query in the `ORDER BY` clause. Whoever wrote this, especially without a comment, should be hanged by body parts important for reproduction.

Comment: Technically that is the *result*.  However, the reality is that the order by clause as shown essentially does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

**The answer is based in Microsoft SQL functionality** [edit:] where subquery in ORDER BY (subquery) expression indicates sort value.

Here's how I see it: since tab2 is not linked to tab1 in a subquery, the SQL can be reduced to:

```
select * from tab1 order by (SELECT <CONSTANT>) desc
```

therefore it's equivalent to:

```
select * from tab1
```

Comment: `select * from tab1 order by <CONSTANT INTEGER> desc` is not equivilant to `select * from tab1`. The former orders by the nth column where n is the integer in question.

Comment: Your edit improves this answer, but is also a bit confusing in that MS SQL is one DBMS where `SELECT * FROM tab1 ORDER BY 3` will sort by the third column. You explicitly state that your answer is based on a DBMS in which the answer is not correct.

Comment: @JeffreyBlake I do not believe that is correct. Run following query in query analyzer: select * from dbo.sysobjects order by (select 10000). Replace (select 10000) with (select 1), or whatever else number you like. You will get same sort result

Comment: That is true. However I get a very different sort order if I run `select * from dbo.sysobjects order by 1000` (which produces an error) or `select * from dbo.sysobjects order by 1` (which sorts by the first column) or `select * from dbo.sysobjects order by 10` (which sorts by the 10th column)

Comment: @JeffreyBlake but that's not what he's running. In order to compare apples to apples, you must run `select * from dbo.sysobjects order by (select 1000)`, `select * from dbo.sysobjects order by (select 1)`, and `select * from dbo.sysobjects order by (select 10)`

Comment: Ah, yes, your after-I-posted edit does reflect that. Strange that `order by 10` has a different effect than `order by (select 10)`

Answer (score 0):

Quite frankly all that query is going to do is return all records from tab1 in some unknown order.

The order by clause is a bit asinine because the value returned will always be the count of all records in tab2.

I suspect it's missing a `where` clause on the `(select count(*) from tab2)` part.  Something along the lines of `(select count(*) from tab2 t where t.tab1id = tab1.id)`  Although it's hard to say without knowing the structure of those two tables.

Comment: what would be the meaning in the case of your suggestion (with where... )?

Answer (score 0):

The `ORDER BY` is equivalent to `ORDER BY 'X'`; that is, it has no effect.  It does not order by the column number referenced by the `count(*)` in the second query -- it is **not** equivalent to `order by 3` if the second table has three rows.

See fiddles for [Oracle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/51516/1/0), [MySQL](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ea67/1/0), and [SQL Server](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/02217/1/0).  If the `ORDER BY` was based on the `count(*)`, the result *should* then be sorted by the third column.  None of them are.  Also, a `count(*)+100` has no effect.